# String conversion and concatenation

Tags: regex, xslt

I have the following line of XML:

```
<indexentry><secondaryie>definition, 3/2/4</secondaryie></indexentry>
```

And I need a regex that matches the above and converts it as below:

```
ABC3(the first number)/P-2(second number)-4(third number)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Regex (at least alone) are not a great tool for this. Use an XML parser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: Please don't [parse XML the Cthulhu way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: Hi @Mauren. Thanks for your comments, here actually i need an xsl transformation where in i use this regex.

Comment: Then anubhava's answer is probably a good way to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes this has solved my problem, thanks guys for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)
```

And from captured groups #1, #2, #3 make your string:

```
ABC3\1/P-2\2-4\3
```